# Swift - Check if responsive or native app

Tags: swift, uiwebview, header, request, server

I created a responsive app and a native app: the native app is basically just a `UIWebView` containing the responsive app.

How can i check on server side (php, etc..) where the request comes from?

Is there any possibility to modifiy requests sent from `UIWebView` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible approaches:

#### URL parameter

You could have a parameter in your URL to indicate the source of the request.

For instance, if the URL if your web app is

```
http://myserver.com/mypath
```

you could use the following URL in your native app's `UIWebView`:

```
http://myserver.com/mypath?src=native
```

On server side, you can retrieve this paramerer, e.g in PHP:

```
$src = $_GET['src'];

if ($src == 'native') {
    // Request from native app
}
```

If your app has multiple pages, then you should modify the way your links are created to propagate this parameter when navigating from one page to another one.

#### Cookie

In the native app, you could manually set a custom cookie which would be sent along your requests and which you would retrieve on server side.

The following post may help you for that: [Is it possible to set a cookie manually using sharedHTTPCookieStorage for a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954382/ios-is-it-possible-to-set-a-cookie-manually-using-sharedhttpcookiestorage-for-a)

Comment: thanks for your answer, so you mean i should modify the url in the UIWebView every time a page is loaded yeah? but how to modify url in uiwebview?

Comment: is it a single-page app (one single URL) or are there several pages ?

Comment: thanks for that, one more question.. how to modify the url in my UIWebView ?

Comment: When instantiating the web view, you choose which URL you want to load initially.