# Pass cookie to UIWebView - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, acaccountstore, nshttpcookie

I have an iOS application which allows the user to use Apple's built in Accounts/Social frameworks to login via Facebook.

One question I have is, is there a way to pass user auth cookie from `ACAccountStore` to a `UIWebView`?

This will mean that, if a user clicks on a link and the built in web view page is shown, they will be able to comment/like/etc without having to login in the web view too.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it won't be possible if you don't control the service you want to be authenticated with in said webviews.

Injecting arbitrary cookies into a `UIWebView` is possible, as described e.g. here: [Is it possible to set a cookie manually using sharedHTTPCookieStorage for a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954382/ios-is-it-possible-to-set-a-cookie-manually-using-sharedhttpcookiestorage-for-a).

Cached auth tokens can be retrieved from `ACAccountCredential`. But OAuth tokens are not session-authenticating cookies.

Facebook does that. Whenever a webview is opened in their iOS client, the user will be automatically authenticated with Facebook in that webview. But they have control over their own service, so they created a mechanism for their iOS client to request session-authenticating cookies (that they then inject into webviews).

In general, though, being a 3rd party developer, you won't be able to reproduce that behavior. Unless of course given service has such mechanism for their own needs and you do some reverse-engineering.

Comment: Ok thanks very much, I will keep these points in mind and have a play around. Thanks.