# How to send cookies with image request in UIWebView

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview

I have a piece of html that I render in a UIWebview. The html is stored locally, but `img` tags embedded in it refer to a remote server.

I would like the `img` request to be accompanied by two cookies that contain auth information.

I am setting 
`[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];` in my app delegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, and I'm adding the cookies to the cookie jar in a post-login step with `[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];` (the cookie domain matches the host that serves the images).

When I debug the UIWebView with `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert(document.cookie)"];` in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` I see an alert with the contents "/".

Firstly, why does the cookie alert contain a single slash?

Secondly, am I doing the right things to send cookies with the image request in the UIWebView?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954382/ios-is-it-possible-to-set-a-cookie-manually-using-sharedhttpcookiestorage-for-a)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Changing `[cookieProperties2 setObject:userId forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];` to `[cookieProperties2 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userId] forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];` fix things.

I was expecting `userId` to be a string (having cast it as such), but it was in fact a `long`. Adding the cookie with a primitive type in its value failed silently.

It's still unclear to me why the javascript cookie debug technique failed.