# How To Set a Cookie for a UIWebView manually in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to set a cookie for a webview in swift. I found a solution, but it is for objective-c. How to do it in Swift?

[Is it possible to set a cookie manually using sharedHTTPCookieStorage for a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954382/ios-is-it-possible-to-set-a-cookie-manually-using-sharedhttpcookiestorage-for-a)

Here is said solution.

Comment: convert that code in swift

Comment: I have no knowledge of objective-c. Sometimes I successfully convert objective-c code to swift, but I could not convert the first part:

[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

Comment: NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookieAcceptPolicy = NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways
this is the conversion of that part in swift

Comment: var cookies:[NSHTTPCookie] = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as [NSHTTPCookie]
for cookie:NSHTTPCookie in cookies as [NSHTTPCookie] {
    if cookie.name as String == "CookieName" {
        var cookieValue : String = "CookieName=" + cookie.value! as String

        //if you want to add to your request
        youRequest.setValue(cookieValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "cookie")
    }
}

Comment: I'd use WKWebView and not the to be deprecated UIWebView: *In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView. Additionally, consider setting the WKPreferences property javaScriptEnabled to NO if you render files that are not supposed to run JavaScript.* --> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/

Comment: I decided to use WKWebView. However Does the method above still works?

Answer (score 28):

You can do something like below using `NSHTTPCookie` and `NSHTTPCookieStorage` to set cookie in `swift`:

```
let URL = "example.com"
let ExpTime = NSTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * 365)

func setCookie(key: String, value: AnyObject) {
    var cookieProps = [
        NSHTTPCookieDomain: URL,
        NSHTTPCookiePath: "/",
        NSHTTPCookieName: key,
        NSHTTPCookieValue: value,
        NSHTTPCookieSecure: "TRUE",
        NSHTTPCookieExpires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: ExpTime)
    ]

    var cookie = NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookieProps)

    NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(cookie!)
}
```

Swift 3 :

```
func setCookie(key: String, value: AnyObject) {
    let cookieProps: [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any] = [
        HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain: URL,
        HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path: "/",
        HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name: key,
        HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value: value,
        HTTPCookiePropertyKey.secure: "TRUE",
        HTTPCookiePropertyKey.expires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: ExpTime)
    ]

    if let cookie = NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookieProps) {
        NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(cookie)
    }
}
```

set `cookieAcceptPolicy` as follow:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookieAcceptPolicy = NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicy.Always
```

**Swift 3**

```
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookieAcceptPolicy = HTTPCookie.AcceptPolicy.always
```

*Note that this was `NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways` in Objective-C and older versions of Swift.*

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nshttpcookiestorage/1410415-cookieacceptpolicy?language=objc) ,"the default cookie accept policy is always" so if always is what you want there is no need to set it explicitly.