# How add cookie to WebView IOS app in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to add a cookie to IOS webView application with swift 4.2 in XCode but it does not work.
Below is one of the code examples I tried to apply and it does not work.
Can anyone help me?

```
let cookieProps:[HTTPCookiePropertyKey:Any]=[
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain:"https://system.fast-apps.com",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path:"/",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name:"isNative",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value:"IwBhE4g"]

    if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProps){    
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
    }
```

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136797/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-a-uiwebview-manually-in-swift

Comment: I updated below code as example from provided link and again it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add cookies to the cookie storage, by implementing the method below:

```swift
var cookies: [HTTPCookie?] = [] {
    didSet {
        cookies.compactMap { $0 }.forEach {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie($0)
        }
    }
}

func addCookie(for url: URL, key: String, value: AnyObject, path: String = "/", isSecure: Bool = true, expirationTime: TimeInterval) {
    cookies.append(HTTPCookie(properties: [
        .originURL: url,
        .path: path,
        .name: key,
        .value: value,
        .secure: isSecure ? "TRUE" : "FALSE",
        .expires: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: expirationTime)
    ]))
}
```

Then, use it as follows:

```swift
addCookie(for: url, key: "someKey", value: someValue, expirationTime: 10000)
```