# Issue while sending cookie to URL with UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, uiwebview, nshttpcookie

I have to open a `URL` in `UIWebview` with a `cookie`. I have to send a `cookie` to `UIWebView`. Only if the `cookie` value will correct then `webview` will load.

Here is my setup:

In my appDelegate's method

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application 
  {
      [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

   }
```

This is how I am creating `cookie` and loading request in `ViewController's` `viewDidLoad` method:

```
//Set Cookie
NSMutableDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"username" forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
[cookieProperties setObject:cookieValue forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
[cookieProperties setObject:@".xyz.com" forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"/" forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];

[cookieProperties setObject:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:2629743] forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];

NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];

//Create Reqeust
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:completeURL]];

[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

**Issue I am facing**

It only works in my simulator. I tested in device and on other mac's it is not working. And sometimes it is not even works in my system.

I am unable to find what is the reason behind it?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954382/ios-is-it-possible-to-set-a-cookie-manually-using-sharedhttpcookiestorage-for-a @rahul

Comment: @PrissyEve I wrote this by using same link as a reference.