# iPhone web view cookie persistence

Tags: uiwebview

When using a web view and closing the app then opening it backup, do cookies persist? (For example to keep a logged in state)

Is this possible?

Comment: Checkout this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837702/nshttpcookiestorage-state-not-saved-on-app-exit-any-definitive-knowledge-docume/15633164#15633164

Answer (score 0):

No, the cookies won't persist.

Here's a solution i hacked together today: https://gist.github.com/maciekish/6268142

Please note that the initial NSURLRequest you pass the UIWebView won't have the cookies unless you set hem.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup Litte fast moderation there perhaps? He asked if cookies will persist when the app is restarted. The answer is no. How is that not an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell you why, but my UIWebView **persists cookies and session by default**, even when I force-close my app. So not really sure about the previous statements.

Answer (score -4):

The cookies works just like mobile browser.
But the only limitation is the cookie is NOT shared with browser, and different webviews has separated cookies storage.

Comment: This is not correct. Cookies in a UIWebView will not persist between app runs.

Comment: the lifetime of cookies will be defined by the web server. it could be session based which expires after webview is closed or one hour/one month which persists.