# Dealing with Cookies in IOS application save an login and delete at logout

Tags: ios, iphone, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am doing a project in login screen am posting email password in response i need to store the cookies and delete the cookies when user logged out  so how can i handle this i tried with NSUrlSession and NSURLConnection but i don't know how to store the cookie and delete the cookie

```
NSString *noteDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user[email]=%@&user[password]=%@", userNameTF.text, passWordTF.text];



 NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPShouldSetCookies = YES;
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{
                                                   @"Accept": @"application/json"
                                                   };
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL/login"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPBody = [noteDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSDictionary * dd = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSString * role = [dd objectForKey:@"role"];
        if ([role isEqualToString:@"user"]) {
            UIStoryboard * storyBD = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            UITabBarController * obj = [storyBD instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tab"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",dd);
    }];
    [postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837702/nshttpcookiestorage-state-not-saved-on-app-exit-any-definitive-knowledge-docume

Comment: does the above code will not work i want to store in login time and delete at logout time

Answer (score 0):

You can also user NSUserDefaults for saving the cookies data

```
- (void)saveCookies{

    NSData *cookiesData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: cookiesData forKey: @"sessionCookies"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}

- (void)loadCookies{

    NSArray *cookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"sessionCookies"]];
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies){
        [cookieStorage setCookie: cookie];
    }

}
```

Delete the cookies data at logout

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"sessionCookies"]
```

//When we saved the data, the key was "sessionCookies" so it must be sessionCookies for this specific saved data. You can name it as you like but then it must be same for saving, retrieving and deleting that specific data.

Please read out the Apple's documentation for NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Okay in the above code if i give like this [self  saveCookies];

Comment: and in logout [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"your key"];

Comment: what is your key here

Comment: its simple string you can name it anything, like sessionCookies

Comment: Ohh okay then tell me when user logins i have to call this two methods and in logout i have to user nsuserdefaults is that right

Comment: Learn about NSUserDefaults here http://possiblemobile.com/2013/03/back-to-basics-forgotten-nsuserdefaults/ or you can search on google

Comment: Please help me with this cookies i know how to use the NSUserDefaults

Comment: Try these, http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2011/04/11/Working-with-cookies-and-http-in-objective-c/ and http://www.cyberspice.org.uk/blog/2009/06/06/using-php-sessions-from-objective-c-and-cocoa/

Comment: still i did not get how to do this